# evernote api : notes in listLinkedNotebooks

Tags: python, api, evernote

with evernote python api,
I can see the shared notebooks

```
notebooks = noteStore.listLinkedNotebooks(authToken) 
print "Found ", len(notebooks), " notebooks:" 
for notebook in notebooks:
    print "  * ", notebook,notebook.guid
```

but, if I try read the note in the notebooks

```
notebooks = noteStore.listLinkedNotebooks(authToken) 
print "Found ", len(notebooks), " notebooks:" 
for notebook in notebooks:
    print "  * ", notebook,notebook.guid
    filter = NoteStore.NoteFilter()
    filter.notebookGuid = notebook.guid
    noteList = noteStore.findNotes(authToken,filter,0,10)
    #print noteList
    for n in noteList.notes:
        print n.title, n.guid
```

I get this error

```
 evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMNotFoundException: 
 EDAMNotFoundException(identifier='Notebook.guid', key='x-y-z')
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this thread and see if it helps: http://forum.evernote.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=17957